# DB Trigger to limit maximum table size in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, triggers

Is it possible, perhaps using DB-triggers to set a maximum table-size in a postgres DB?

For example, say I have a table called: `Comments`.

From the user perspective, this can be done as frequently as possible, but say I only want to store the 100 most recent comments in the DB. So what I want to do is have a trigger that automatically maintains this. I.e. when more than 100 comments are there, it deletes the oldest one, etc.

Could someone help me with writing such a trigger?

Answer (score 2):

I think a trigger is the wrong tool for the job; although it is possible to implement this.  Something about spawning a "delete" from an executing insert makes the hair on my neck neck stand up.  You will generate a lot of locking and possibly contention that way; and inserts should generally not generate locks.

To me this says "stored procedure" all the way.

But I also think you should ask yourself, "why delete" old comments?  Deletes are an anathema.  Better just limit them when you display them.  If you are really worried about the size of the table, use a TEXT column.  Postgres will maintain these in a shadow table and full scans of the original table will blaze along just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Limiting to 100 comments per user is rather simple, e.g.

```
delete from comments where user_id = new.user_id
order by comment_date desc offset 100;
```

Limiting the byte size is trickier. You'd need to calculate the relevant row sizes and that won't account for index sizes, dead rows, etc. At best you'd use the admin functions to get the table size but these won't yield the size per user, only the total size.

Comment: The clause DELETE in PostgreSQL does not support ORDER BY. You need to use a subquery.

Answer (score 0):

We could in theory create a table of 100 dummy records and then simply overwrite them with the actual comments. Once we pass the 100th we will overwrite the 1st one, etc.

This way we are suppose to keep the same size of the table, but that is not possible, because an [update is equivalent to delete,insert](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-vacuum.html) in Postgresql. So the size of the table will continue to grow.

So if the objective is not to overflow the disk drive then once the disk is full at 80% a "vacuum full" should be performed to free up disk space. "Vacuum full" requires disk space by itself. If you kept the records to a fixed number then there will be an effect of the vacuum. Also there seems to be cases where vacuum [can fail](http://rhaas.blogspot.fr/2011/03/troubleshooting-stuck-vacuums.html).